# How do you prevent a redirect loopback when your mobile site calls your full site?

Tags: iis, mobile, http-referer

I just added a dotmobi mobile site from Network Solutions to complement my full site.  I was able to successfully redirect smartphones (but not iPads) to the site with these two URL rewrites on my IIS server:

```
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="ipad" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="None" />
</rule>
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone|android|iphone" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.wkmclaughlin.mobi" />
</rule>
```

My problem now:  How do I bypass redirection on requests from the mobile site itself to the main site?  I've been playing around with {HTTP_REFERER} for hours and getting nowhere.

p.s.  The mobile site only lets you specify the root of your domain -- you can't specify a page as a flag to url rewrite.

Comment: Add a condition to your second rule to verify the incoming request host name does not match .mobi.

Comment: @lexli I added
 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".mobi" negate="true" />
to the conditions of the second rule and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Edit your question please. It is ugly to see such in a comment.

Comment: @lexli Sorry, I was already editing it when you responded.

Comment: @LexLi  Please resume.  I also tried that pattern as just "mobi" without the period.

Comment: @LexLi   Could you please just tell me what server variable I should be using?  I think you're taking great offense at a harmless mistake that I was in the process of immediately fixing.